# How to create expanders for multiple columns using python and streamlit?

Tags: python, for-loop, streamlit

i am trying to create function that display 12 columns that have expander and each expander have a multiselect widget with table.

How can i do this ?

## my code:

```
def display_month_list(df,month):
      df_test = df.iloc[:;[0,1,2,3]]
      option_list = df_test["categories"].unique().tolist()
     
      selected_option = st.multiselect("Select Category",option_list)
      if selected_option:
            df_test = df_test[df_test["categories"].isin(selected_option)]
      st.write(df_test)

col1,col2,col3,col4 = st.columns(4)
col5,col6,col7,col8 = st.columns(4)
col9,col10,col11,col12 = st.columns(4)

with col1:
   with st.expander("cat1"):
        display_month_list(df,"cat1")

with col2:
   with st.expander("cat2"):
        display_month_list(df,"cat2")
```

and so on....

My question is how to add this function in each column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More than 1 Multiselect need a unique key. See my sample code on how to supply unique key.

### Code

```
def display_month_list(i):
    selected_option = st.multiselect("Select Category", ['a', 'b', 'c'], key=i)
    # st.write(f'your stuff')

cols = st.columns(4)
for i, c in enumerate(cols):
    with c:
        with st.expander(f'cat {i+1}'):
            display_month_list(i+1)

cols = st.columns(4)
for i, c in enumerate(cols):
    with c:
        with st.expander(f'cat {i+5}'):
            display_month_list(i+5)

cols = st.columns(4)
for i, c in enumerate(cols):
    with c:
        with st.expander(f'cat {i+9}'):
            display_month_list(i+9)
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: But the problem  is that when i have more than 500 records that are displayed as  expanders it will crash the app and stop

Comment: Do you mean to say you need 500 expanders?

Comment: Let say i have 1000 records.

Until now i am using table to display results based on filtering, where each row is a  record.
What i am trying to do is to convert these rows into expanders or cards.

Comment: It seems like you are raising another issue. Please accept that this current issue is now solved as you only mentioned 12 columns/expanders. Then create a new issue on massive use of columns/expanders. One more advice. If the app crashes be sure to save the error messages if there is. The error messages might point us to understand the issue.